# Performance improvement of simulink coder over accelerated models

Tags: matlab, simulink

I wonder if there's some experience out there, how much performance can be gained from using the Simulink Coder to generate models over running the model in (rapid) accelerator mode?

For instance, how does it compare to the quite dramatic improvements from not-accelerated to accelerated models?

I know this is kind of vague and probably depends on the specifics of a model, but I'd be happy with examplary numbers.

Comment: How much speedup you get really depends on how optimal the C code that you've written for your SFunctions is...

Comment: Are you trying to simulate a model by generating code with Simulink Coder and then running it outside of Simulink?

Comment: In short: i dont know ;) This is about a generalized application that is supposed to be able to have simulink-models (from trivial gain-blocks to protected s-function blocks) as a kind of plugin. The application itself is generally about analyzing/visualizing the outputs of (e.g.) the simulink models. The models might be run several thousand times. So I'm wondering wether the coder might be worth its price in terms of performance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you will really find speed improvement anecdotes that helpful, as your results are going to be highly dependent on your own implementation.

That said, the following reference on [How Acceleration Modes Work](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/how-the-acceleration-modes-work.html) might be useful to you.

As described in this link...

> The Accelerator mode generates and links code into a
>   C-MEX S-function. Simulink uses this acceleration target code to
>   perform the simulation...
>
> ...the model methods are separate from the Simulink
>   software and are part of the Acceleration target code. A C-MEX
>   S-function API communicates with the Simulink software, and a MEX API
>   communicates with MATLAB. The target code executes in the same process
>   as MATLAB and Simulink.

The link goes on to describe Rapid Acceleration, as such:

> The Rapid Accelerator mode creates a Rapid Accelerator standalone
>   executable from your model. This executable includes the solver and
>   model methods, but it resides outside of MATLAB and Simulink. It uses
>   External mode (see Host/Target Communication) to communicate with
>   Simulink.

(Note that the actual link has some nice diagrams that help to illustrate this architecture).

I think that there are a few important things to takeaway from these descriptions.  First, in Accelerator Mode, code is only generated for the model methods; however, in Rapid Accelerator Mode, code is also generated for the solver.  In either case there will be some overhead due to communication between the generated code and Simulink (though in general that overhead would be greater in non-rapid accelerator mode).

Now, whether you are going to see significant differences between these acceleration modes and full-on code generation will most likely depend on how you would be using the generated code.  You had stated that your application is intended to essentially analyze/visualize the outputs of simulink models.  Do you intend for you application, itself, to be a Simulink model?  If so, I imagine your workflow would be that you generate code for the "plug-in" model and then incorporate this into your "parent" model as an s-function.  Based on the descriptions given above, my gut feeling is that you would not see much of a performance improvement compared to accelerator mode.

However, if your application is to be implemented outside of Simulink, then code generation would definitely be the way to go.  In this case, you've completely eliminated the overhead of communicating with Simulink.  In this workflow, you could, for example, generate a stand-alone executable from the "plug-in" model, execute that model to get the outputs, and then simply load those outputs for analysis and visualization into your application.  Your application could be written in any language you want.  In fact, you could even still write your application in MATLAB -- the key point, though, being that your application runs once the stand-alone executable (generated from the "plug-in" model) has *finished* executing, rather than interfacing with the plug-in model *while* it is executing.

Comment: Yup, that pretty much sums it up! Another useful link to compare performance of the different simulation modes: http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/comparing-performance.html

Comment: I've come across these links/manuals as well. Unfortunately, the "Comparing Performance"-plot does not include a "Simulink Coder" line which was, what I was originally trying to find. The fact that both accelerator-modes already produce compiled models to some degree, led me to the question whether the Code-Generation would improve things performance-wise. Meanwhile, I'm doubting this... It's clear though, that performance is not the "declared" goal of the code-generation toolbox anway.

Comment: I generally agree. The main purpose of Simulink Coder is to allow generation of standalone code, and to a great extent, the speed improvement aspect of code generation is already available without Simulink Coder.  Something else to consider -- rather than shelling out for Simulink Coder, maybe you'd be better off looking into the parallel computing tools for matlab/simulink.  Your description of your usecase sounds sort of like a Monte Carlo approach. If the thousands of simulations you plan to run could be parallelized, that would offer a significant speed-up.